# Finding the number of pages on a website with soup.findall unicode problems

Tags: python, string, unicode, beautifulsoup, findall

Hi I am trying to find the number of pages on a website using Python 2.7 and Beautifulsoup. I try to get the number of pages from pagination row using this code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request("https://www.sikayetvar.com", None,headers)
resp  = urllib2.urlopen(req)
html = resp.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
pages = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class' : 'pagination row'})
for page in pages:
   print page.text
```

the output is the following:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
...
807

I only need the number 807 however soup.findall receives this as unicode I tried this with type. Should I turn this into a string and find max number in which case the (...) would create a problem,I think or should I try to find the last element of findall but again this isn't a list it is unicode. I really need some help thank you.

Comment: What does `int(pages[-1].text)` give you?

Comment: @JonClements right below pages I wrote ,s = int(pages[-1].text)
print s, it says: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ...807'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't install urllib. So i am going with `requests` library. You can install it with `pip install requests`

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

response = requests.get("https://www.sikayetvar.com/a101", headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')

#This will you all a tags in div that has pagination class
pages = soup.select('div.pagination a')

#Last element is next page. The previous is your last page number.
#So we are going to take second last item

print(pages[-2].text)
#Output is 807
```

Comment: @Selçuk, `urllib[2]` is part of the standard library, you don't need to install it.